# Retrieve comments from website using disqus

Tags: web-scraping, disqus

I would like to write a scraping script to retrieve comments from cnn articles. For example, this article: http://www.cnn.com/2012/01/19/politics/gop-debate/index.html?hpt=hp_t1

I realize that cnn uses disqus for their comment discussion. As the comment loading is not webpage-based (ie, prev page, next page) and is dynamic (ie, need to click "load next 25"), I have no idea how to retrieve all the 5000+ comments for this article.

Any idea or suggestion?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Are you asking how to scrape? or do you know how to scrape using a certain tool and you need assistance with scraping a disqus-based comment system? if its the latter then retag you question to include the name of the tool

Comment: Hi Boaz.Jan, I am asking how to scrape. For webpage-based newswire page such as http://www.guardian.co.uk/politics/2012/jan/10/scottish-independence-referendum-autumn-2014?commentpage=1, we just need to replace commentpage by 2, 3, 4.. and we can do a http get to download the page and scrape it. With disqus, seems that there is no way to retrieve all comments with http get...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The option for scraping (other then getting the page), which might be less robust (depends on you're needs) but will offer a solution for the problem you have, is to use some kind of wrapper around a full fledged web browser and literally code the usage pattern and extract the relevant data. Since you didn't mention which programming language you know, I'll give 3 examples: 1) Watir - ruby, 2) Watin - IE & Firefox via .net, 3) Selenium - IE via C#/Java/Perl/PHP/Ruby/Python

I'll provide a little example using Watin & C#:

```
IE browser = new IE();
browser.GoTo(YOUR CNN URL);
List visibleComments = Browser.List(Find.ById("dsq-comments"));
//do your scraping thing
Link moreComments = Browser.Link(Find.ByClass("dsq-paginate-append-text");
moreComments.click();
//wait util ajax ended by searching for some indicator
Browser.WaitUntilContainsText(SOME TEXT);
//do your scraping thing
```

Notice:
I'm not familiar with disqus, but it might be a better option to force all the comments to show by looping the Link & click parts of the code I posted until all the comments are visible and the scrape the List element dsq-comments

Answer (score 7):

I needed to get comments via scraping a page that had disqus comments via ajax. Because they were not rendered on the server, I had to call the disqus api. In the source code, you will need the identifier code:

```
var identifier = "456643" // take note of this from the page source
// this is the ident url query param in the following js request
```

also,look in the js source code to get the pages public key, and forum name. Place these in the url where appropriate.

I used javascript nodejs to test this, ie :

```
var request = require("request");

var publicKey  = "pILMw27bsbJsdfsdQDh9Eh0MzAgFL6xx0hYdsdsdfaIfBHRvLGqFFQ09st";

var disqusUri = "https://disqus.com/api/3.0/threads/listPosts.json?&api_key=" + publicKey + "&thread:ident=456643&forum=nameOfForumFromSource";

request(disqusUri, function(res,status,err){
    console.log(res.body);

    if(err){
        console.log("ERR: " + err);
    }
});
```