# How to create a disqus url query to retrieve comments

Tags: disqus

I am very new to Disqus and even more so on a developer level. I am trying to follow the documentation of how to retrieve disqus comments (so that I can store them on my own database for a particular use). 
I don't fully understand how to create the url query. For example: I see 'listposts' listed under the 'thread' and 'catagories' category. In each I am asked for additional info, such as thread id, category id, or, under thread, you can use thread:ident=my-identifier&forum=bobross

Where do I get all of these values? I have a disqus account and made a few test comments (and replied to some as well), but don't know what to do past there.

After I figure all this out, to actually put this into code, do I need any curl calls (for the GET, because I'm trying to pull data, not update) to actually get the data? Or do I just do an ajax call with json reponse?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8937785/retrieve-comments-from-website-using-disqus.

Comment: I don't understand what that answer is. If you could explain it to me, that would be great! I am programming in php.